How to handle FileNotFoundException in python
I have a function to read avro files(day-wise folders) from a path and write it to
same path(aggregating to month-wise folders). The function works fine if the folders have .avro files.
But I get an error if the folders are empty.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No avro files found. If files don't have .avro extension, set ignoreExtension to true

I have handled with try and except block. Even then I'm getting the error. This is function below.
def aggregate_data(path_to_source, input_format, output_format, output_table_format='avro'):
    all_input_dates = [str(fileStatus.getPath()).split('/')[-1] for fileStatus in
                        lake.listStatus(fs.Path(path_to_source))
                        if 'latest' not in str(fileStatus.getPath())]
                        
    all_output_dates = list(set(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, input_format).strftime(output_format)
                        for i in all_input_dates if validate_date(i, input_format) - {datetime.date.today().strftime(output_format)})
                        
    print("***** {0} *****".format(path_to_source))
    
    try:
        for _partition in all_output_dates:
            src_df = spark.read.option("ignoreExtension":"true"). format(output_table_format)\
                        .load(os.path.join(path_to_source, '{0}*'.format(_partition)))
                        
            agg_df = src_df.repartition(estimate_part_num(src_df)).write.mode('overwrite')\
                        .format(output_table_format).save(os.path.join(path_to_source, _partition))
                        
            command_exist = ['hadoop', 'fs', '-rm', '-r', os.path.join(path_to_source, '{0}[.]*'. format(_partition))]
            subprocess.call(command_exist)
    except FileNotFoundException as e: 
        print("**** Exception occured ****".format(path_to_source),e)

How to handle FileNotFoundException in python

Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

The error occurs in the line where I read the data. That's because there are no avro files inside a folder. But I'm not sure how to handle it

I tried with  except FileNotFoundError. Even this failed.

You're getting a Java exception, not a Python one. I'm guessing spark.read...load(...) calls a Java utility or module (or Kotlin etc. which uses the Java runtime library). You can't catch that, you have to check that the files exist first.

Yeah why is it Java?

Evidently, java.io.FileNotFoundException is not the same as FileNotFoundException.

Tried multiple ways to handle it. But no luck. Now I check if file exists and then proceed with next steps
